# Why is subject-auxiliary inversion NOT triggered by 'so' as a correlative conjunction?

Tags: inversion

Source: p 258, *A Student's Introduction to English Grammar* (2005), by Huddleston & Pullum

> [1.] The main elements that trigger inversion like this
>   include:
>   ... 
>   expressions containing ***so*** or ***only***, as in [46]
>   - or *Sue is going, and `so` am I*. ...

I ask this question only for 'so' in a correlative conjunction (eg 'Just as ..., so ...'), for which I usually witness subject-auxiliary inversion.
Thus, for the main clause, why were **so** and **is** NOT inverted?
I would've written:

> [3.] ... **so** **is** *protensio* derived ...

[Source](https://books.google.com/books?id=kZ03AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA54&lpg=PA54&dq=protasis+etymology&source=bl&ots=vl6gUC_85D&sig=_HSq3XfMyDvv6YlRnEneHZFma_M&hl=en&sa=X&ei=llhnVcazMIipgwSipoKgAg&ved=0CFQQ6AEwCg#v=onepage&q=protasis%20etymology&f=false): p 54, *The Logic of Apuleius* ..., 
 edited by [David George Londey](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/713659628?journalCode=rajp20), Carmen J. Johanson

> [2.] For just as the word *protasis* 
>   is derived from a Greek verb of holding out or offering, viz., *proteino*, **so** 
>   *protensio* is derived from the matching Latin verb *protendo*.

Footnote: I encountered this  quote while researching [the etymology of 'protasis'](https://www.google.com/search?q=protasis&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=jlhnVba2CpPmgwS54oD4DQ#q=protasis+etymology&start=0).

Comment: Sometimes it does--*As Maine goes, so goes the nation*--sometimes it doesn't. The inverted construction is old-fashioned; it is giving way to an uninverted construction which makes the parallelism clearer.

Comment: I guess I'm not 100% what is even being asked here, but would this be more appropriate on English SE? What about this makes it an ELL question?

Comment: @StoneyB: I think that's a slightly different use of *so* from the one in the question. The example in the question has the form "Just as [complete statement], so [complete statement]", whereas your example has the form "As [statement with an empty slot for an adverbial complement], so [statement with empty slot for an adverbial complement]." Both of these uses of *so* can be used with or without inversion, but I *think* that the use in your example is more often found with inversion than the use in the OP's example.

Comment: I think the passive may be implicated here.

Answer (score 1):

“So” can be inverted when it means “in that fashion”

> “[As Maine goes, so goes the nation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As_Maine_goes,_so_goes_the_nation).”

(Ie. whichever candidate is favored by the electorate in the US state of Maine, that same candidate is favored by the nation as a whole.)

When “so” means “therefore”, no inversion:

> “[The world wants to be deceived, so let it be deceived](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mundus_vult_decipi,_ergo_decipiatur)."

(The world wants something, therefore it should get it.)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it isn't a very happily constructed sentence altogether.

> For just as the word *protasis* is derived from a Greek verb of holding out or offering, viz., *proteino*, so *protensio* is derived from the matching Latin verb *protendo*.

It's wobbly in more ways than two. "... derived from a Greek verb of holding out or offering" is a bit awkward, and the uninverted construction is downright lame, making the sentence choppy and needlessly difficult to read through.

The inverted construction is not old-fashioned; it's very much in use today. The uninverted construction is not taking over: it's merely allowed for the sake of those who are so forgiving as to suffer gladly sentences whose most striking feature is phraseological vulgarity.

Consider this:

> For just as the word *protasis* is derived from a Greek verb that literally means "to extend forward," viz., *proteino*, so is *protensio* derived from the matching Latin verb *protendo*.

And, voilà - suddenly it's smooth and free-flowing, a soaring bird of a sentence. This isn't rocket science.